# Is it OK to pass pandas GroupBy functions as argument in python function? and how should I pass their arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like a function that takes a GroupBy operations such as mean(), max() as argument. I'm not sure as to how to include arguments for these functions. For example, in the case of quantile, there is the argument for telling which quantile, so in such case I should be able to provide this extra argument.

```
def compute_moment(data, moment = pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean):

    # This builds columns that we will use to group.
    group_data = data.rank(pct = True).round(1).add_suffix('_grouper')
    df = data.join(group_data)

    out = []
    for col in data.columns:
        #This is the key step, what if I want moment to be, say quantile(q = .7)?
        x = df.groupby(col+'_grouper').mean()[col] #no problem here
        y = moment(df.groupby(col+'_grouper'))['y']

        out += [pd.concat([x, y], axis=1)]

    return out

>>> out = compute_moment(data, pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean)

#output is a list of dataframes like this one:
>>> print out[0]

              rho         y
rho_grouper                    
0.0          0.024998  0.035754
0.1          0.099908  0.036522
0.2          0.199903  0.032319
0.3          0.299908  0.038726
0.4          0.399907  0.034523
0.5          0.499907  0.031123
0.6          0.599909  0.031352
0.7          0.699908  0.030531
0.8          0.799902  0.031277
0.9          0.899904  0.028456
1.0          0.974912  0.029378
```

I would like to know how to do this correctly, or why not, a simpler alternative to have a function that applies these groupby operations, and lets me pass arguments if necessary.

By the way, is it OK to pass a pandas.GroupBy function as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to pass anything you want, if it works and serves you well.
You can pass function's agrs either as an additional dict/tuple argument, or just use *args and **kwargs.

still, it is unclear what you want to achieve here. 
First, It looks like you're messing with `data` and `df` in your function.
Second, if I understand correctlly, `pd.core.groupby.GroupBy` is a class of a data-object - it is what you'll get from `df.groupby`, not the other way around. thus, you shouldn't use it here.

However, you can simply pass strings or agg functions as an arguement, and then apply them in `.agg` method:

```
def foo(df, agg='mean'):
    momentum = df.groupby('grouper').agg(agg)
```

this way you can pass either strings( 'mean', 'sum') or arrays, or dicts, or even functions into `agg`arguement). Moreover, in this case array will result in getting all functions in the array applied to all columns, so you don't have to join and you don't have to loop.

To learn more on how `groupby` work, take a look here, for example:
https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_apply_operations_to_groups.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I had to write the full name of the groupby function (`pd.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean`) because if just write `mean` it would tell me _mean is not defined_.
My question is that if instead of `mean` I choose `quantile` i need to have an extra argument `quantile(q = .7)` and I'm not sure how to handle that situation from the definition of the foo function.

Comment: Use *args and **kwargs